Converting a set of reactions represented by strings separated by spaces, or by newline, to a list of similar strings
In the Macaulay package ReactionNetworks.m2, a set of reactions is represented as
{AB1-->B+C 
 C2-->D}

with  new line  separating the first reaction AB1-->B+C of the second, which seems to be converted in Times when I paste this in Mathematica. After pasting, I get
FullForm [{AB1-- > B + C C2-- > D}]

is
List[Greater[Decrement[AB1], Plus[B, Times[C, Decrement[C2]]], D]]

I would like to have    a Mathematica function to convert the above to  the format
{"AB1"->"B"+"C",  "C2"->"D"} 

(used in the package ReactionKinetics.wl). Note the arrows --> changed to ->, separators changed to comma, and " " are put around each symbol.
The answer provided below is correct for the input I had provided at first, but  that input was wrong, sorry.
I guess a first step could be to replace the Times introduced by Mathematica when pasting by , Or, to replace --> by -> . But, I don't know enough about patterns to do this

Assuming the Input is {"AB1-->B+C C2-->D"} (space between your reactions), you can use StringSplit as follows:
ReplaceAll[str_String :> Total[StringSplit[str, "+"]]][
Rule @@@ Fold[StringSplit, First@{"AB1-->B+C C2-->D"}, {" ", "-->"}]]


{"AB1" -> "B" + "C", "C2" -> "D"}

Or using the Input {"AB1-->B+C"   "C2-->D"}:
ReplaceAll[str_String :> Total[StringSplit[str, "+"]]][
Rule @@@ StringSplit[First@(List @@@ {"AB1-->B+C"   "C2-->D"}), "-->"]]


{"AB1" -> "B" + "C", "C2" -> "D"}

We can build ConvertReactions as follows:
SetAttributes[ConvertReactions, HoldFirst];
ConvertReactions[expr_] := 
  Module[{strexpr, spstrexpr, spbyrule, toexp},
   strexpr = 
    StringCases[ToString[Hold[expr]], 
     "Hold" ~~ "[" ~~ "{" ~~ a__ ~~ "}" ~~ "]" :> 
      StringReplace[a, "-- >" -> "->"]];
   spstrexpr = First@StringSplit[strexpr, " "];
   spbyrule = SplitBy[spstrexpr, StringContainsQ["->"]];
   toexp = Map[ToExpression@*StringJoin@*Flatten]@Partition[spbyrule, 2];
   Rule @@@ 
    MapAt[Apply[Plus], 
     Map[ToString, 
      Map[MapApply[List]]@MapApply[List]@toexp, {-1}], {All, 2}]
   ];

Testing ConvertReactions:
ConvertReactions[{AB1-- > B + C1   C2-- > D2}]

ConvertReactions[{AB1-- > B + C1   C2-- > D2  C3-- > D3}]


{"AB1" -> "B" + "C1", "C2" -> "D2"}


{"AB1" -> "B" + "C1", "C2" -> "D2", "C3" -> "D3"}


Thanks! This a bit confusing for me. In the output, I only see {AB1 -> B + C, C2 -> D}, which is not the same, but when I copy the output in an input cell, I get indeed {"AB1" -> "B" + "C", "C2" -> "D"}  I am surely missing something
